# TaxonomyClientService.GetTermSets 400 bad request

Tags: sharepoint

What is wrong with this SOAP request?  I keep on getting 400 bad request error.

```
<S:Body>
<GetTermSets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/">
  <sharedServiceIds>
     <termStoreIds>
       <termStoreId>27a0a321-083f-4688-8b6e-d86b7ab42de9</termStoreId>
     </termStoreIds>
  </sharedServiceIds>   
  <termSetIds>
    <termSetIds><termSetId>cb1b9444-159d-48c3-b9a7-19ebd612e796</termSetId></termSetIds>
  </termSetIds>
  <lcid>1033</lcid>
  <clientTimeStamps>
     <timeStamps><timeStamp>2304823424</timeStamp></timeStamps>
  </clientTimeStamps>
  <clientVersions><versions><version>1</version></versions></clientVersions>
</GetTermSets>
</S:Body>
```

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with this for a long time as well, and had extrapolated the same request from all the examples that I could find online.

But I managed to get it working by looking up "MS-EMMWS" (my working example below)
[MS-EMMWS - Protocol Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958731%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
           <GetTermSets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/">
              <sharedServiceIds>&lt;sspIds&gt;&lt;sspId&gt;0d18c636-63d4-452b-b094-6de97ee5159d&lt;/sspId&gt;&lt;/sspIds&gt;
              </sharedServiceIds><termSetIds>&lt;termSetIds&gt;&lt;termSetId&gt;48508451-17d5-4bdb-b1c9-7f096f680352&lt;/termSetId&gt;&lt;/termSetIds&gt;</termSetIds><lcid>1033</lcid>
              <clientTimeStamps>&lt;dateTimes&gt;&lt;dateTime&gt;1900-01-01T00:00:00&lt;/dateTime&gt;&lt;/dateTimes&gt;</clientTimeStamps>
              <clientVersions>&lt;versions&gt;&lt;version&gt;0&lt;/version&gt;&lt;/versions&gt;</clientVersions></GetTermSets>
        </soap:Body>
     </soap:Envelope>
```